# UIPanGestureRecognizer not accepting UIView target

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a simple demo application where I am trying to dynamically add a UITextView with a UIView directly behind it (as a background). But every time I compile and test the pan gesture, I get this error:

**-[UIView detectPan:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e7fc30**

Here is my sample code where I create the UIView's and assign the UIPanGesture:

```
CGRect textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 44);

// Create a TextField
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
textField.layer.zPosition = 100001;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

// Create the Text Background View
UIView *textBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];
textBG.layer.zPosition = 100000;
[self.view addSubview:textBG];

self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:textBG action:@selector(detectPan:)];
```

And my detectPan method:

```
-(void)detectPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog(@"inside detectPan");
}
```

Is there some step I am missing in my implementation? I swear this exact same approach has worked for me in the past, but now it just doesn't work at all. Very confusing!

Comment: have you added gesture to any control?

Comment: [self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.panRecognizer];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem, because it is easy to be mislead by the word "target" in `-initWithTarget:action:`

Try changing `initWithTarget:textBG` to `initWithTarget:self` and things should work.

So your new line of code will look like this:

```
self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectPan:)];
```

The reason people get tripped up the word "target", is because they think of the "target" as the "object I want to target with my custom code" (i.e. "The UIView I want to drag around the screen"), when instead, they should be thinking of the target of a UIPanGestureRecognizer as "the UIView that is currently containing the object I want to drag across screen", or in other words "the UIView that owns the coordinate space I want to use in order to calculate the pan gesture translations"

Like this:

```
-----------------------
|                     |
|  Containing UIView -|-----> "THE TARGET"
|                     |       The "target" owns the x,y coordinate space where the
|    ------------     |       UIPanGestureRecognizer will calculate the movements of
|    |          |     |       your "drag" or "pan" across the screen.
|    |  UIView  |     |
|    | (textBG) |     |
|    |          |     |
|    ------------     |
|                     |
-----------------------
```

So, in your example, your app is crashing because you are setting your textBG as the target, and detectPan as the action, which is essentiualy saying "when a pan gesture is detected within the textBG object, call the detectPan method of the textBG object", but you don't have a detectPan method on the textBG object, you only have a detectPan method that exists within the parent of textBG (i.e. "self"). This is why you are getting the **unrecognized selector sent to instance** error in this case, because your program can't find a -detectPan: method associated to your textBG object.

Hope this helps!